# Maintaining 'this' when calling a function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to go from this:

```
$("#btnminus").mousedown(function () {
    $(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);
}
```

to this:

```
function btnPressed() {
    $(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);
}
$("#btnminus").mousedown(function () {
    btnPressed();
}
```

Apparently, it's not that easy. JSLint gives me a 'strict violation' problem, which I don't know what means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's even easier, just reference the function, and the `this-value` will be the element

```
$("#btnminus").mousedown(btnPressed);
```

When you call the function within another anonymous function with no context, the `this-value` will be the `window` *(in sloppy mode, in strict it would be `undefined`)*, and not the element, because that's the default execution context when nothing else is specified.

Here's [**some examples**](https://jsfiddle.net/3kwyenyv/1/) of how to set the `this-value` when calling a function inside an event handle.

As JSLint has a tremendous amount of stupidity built in, and lints all sorts of things that aren't neccessarely a problem, you can either

1. Stop using it
2. Ignore the error, as it's cause by a `this` in a function that JSLint doesn't know what is
3. add the `this: true` directive to your file, to make JSLint ignore such errors

-

```
/*jslint this: true*/

"use strict"

function btnPressed() {
    $(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);
}

$("#btnminus").mousedown(btnPressed);
```

will validate

Comment: Thank you for your exhaustive answer. However, JSLint still flags strict violations for this `$(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);` line of code.

Comment: @Willege - I've updated the answer to adress that as well.

Comment: Now the program is stopping on the comment and 'this' in the comment is flagged as unexpected, too.

Comment: That's because JSLint is stupid, horrible crap that you shouldn't be listening to. However, if I take [**this code**](https://jsfiddle.net/ok4eh7ys/1/) and paste it into [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), it validates just fine, so it's clearly working.

Comment: Yep, it validates, sorry for saying 'the program is stopping'. I meant to say that JSLint is stopping scanning. At any rate, I'll try not to take JSLint so seriously from now on.

Answer (score 0):

> JSLint gives me a 'strict violation' problem, which I don't know what means.

This means you are using `strict` mode, and that error tells you that here

```
function btnPressed() {
    $(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);
}
```

You are using `this` in the context of a standalone function, which is not the `#btnminus` element.

In this code

```
$("#btnminus").mousedown(function () {
    btnPressed();
}
```

`this` inside the anonymous function is correct because jQuery manages that for you, but when you call `btnPressed()` its `this` it not the correct one.

You could simply do `$("#btnminus").mousedown(btnPressed);` and everything will be ok.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, but JSLint still tells me there's a strict violation. I also tried to add this comment `/*jshint validthis: true */` to no avail.

Comment: The line in the body of `function btnPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Use event.currentTarget instead of this:

```js
function btnPressed(event) {
  var $el = $(event.target);
  $(this).animate({width: "95%", height: "95%"}, 50);
}

$("#btnminus").mousedown(btnPressed);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnminus">Minus</button>
```

Comment: In event listeners, `this` is `event.currentTarget`, not `event.target`.